# c# List<T> RemoveRange what happens to removed items?

Tags: c#

After using RemoveRange, items appear to remain in memory. There's no other reference that I know of to these items. Should I just use a workaround where I copy the items I want and kill the old list completely?

Made an example to illustrate:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bmp = new Bitmap(5000, 5000, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    pictureBox1.Width = bmp.Width;pictureBox1.Height = bmp.Height;
    bmp2 = new Bitmap(some_image_file);//500x500 bitmap
}
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bitmap_list.Add(new Bitmap(bmp));
    Graphics.FromImage(bmp).DrawImage(bmp2, e.X - bmp2.Width / 2, e.Y - bmp2.Height / 2);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{// where do the items go? memory is not freed until running a manual GC
    bitmap_list.RemoveRange(1, bitmap_list.Count - 1);
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{// if this is not clicked, memory will run out even after clearing the list
    // down to one item
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the last reference to an object does not destroy it and release memory, instead it will happen sometime later when the garbage collector runs.

However, since your items are disposable (e.g. they implement `IDisposable`), you should call `Dispose()` of the items you are removing, for instance before doing the removal from the list. This will have the instances clean up unmanaged resources deterministically instead of waiting for the GC and finalizers to run, and thus have the behavior more like you expected it.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I normally use dispose a lot but didn't think of it here for some reason.